# How I can create several Edit texts in android studio only with a button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want create N edit text with pressing a button only once. for example I enter quantity of edit texts=20[enter image description here][1], when I press button all of 20 edit texts created in several rows and columns.

Any solutions??

sample picture for better solution [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wevZN.png

my code is in below

```
 String Type,number,tedad;
TextView pazireshnum;
EditText tedadbattri;
String id=ID;
private LinearLayout mLayout;
private EditText mEditText;
private ImageButton mButton;
int k = -1;
int flag,i;
int hint=1;
ArrayList<String> applnserverinstnos = new ArrayList<String>();
public static EditText textView[] = new EditText[100];
@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_list);

    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln1);
   // mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn);
    tedadbattri=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed7);
    tedadbattri.setText("0");
    pazireshnum=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    tedad= tedadbattri.getText().toString();
    int Tedad = Integer.parseInt(tedad);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {

                        k++;
                        flag = k;
                        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        lparams.setMargins(5, 10, 5, 10);
                        textView[flag] = new EditText(CheckList.this);
                        textView[flag].setLayoutParams(lparams);
                        textView[flag].setId(flag);
                        textView[flag].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    mLayout.addView(textView[flag]);
                    textView[flag].setHint("باتری"+hint);
                    hint++;
                    textView[flag].setId(hint);
                    textView[flag].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
                    textView[flag].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border4);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check this procedure , suppose 20 can be divided 4 columns with 5 rows . So run `for loop` on columns and rows to add `editText` view to `TableRow` with `TableLayout` .

Example `main_activity.xml` where used `TableLayout` to add EditText .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="283dp" />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/table">
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now try the code -

```
   mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int total = 20;  // quantity of edit texts 20
            final int columns = 4;
            final int rows = total / columns;  // in this case rows would be 5


            TableLayout myTable = findViewById(R.id.table);

            //Params for TableRow and TableLayout
            final TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            final TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
           //apply to clear
            myTable.removeAllViews();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                TableRow tableRows = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());


                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                    editText.setText("voltage" + total--);
                    tableRows.addView(editText, rowParams);
                }
                myTable.addView(tableRows, tableParams);

            }
        }
    });
```

Output-
[image]

Comment: your answer is ok but I have a problem with this answer. when I press the button again and again every time make 20 extra edit text. I want if I press button make only 20 edit texts and replace with previous edit texts.

Comment: Just remove all views before start the loop `myTable.removeAllViews();` . check updtaed answer I have added just now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop and create `EditText`s in that loop and add them to a `FlowLayout` container; Maybe [this](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout) implementation or [`ConstraintLayout's Flow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow)

Comment: I want create 20 or more edit texts that after that enter value for all of them. this is a battery voltage check list. every machine has some battery. I want to enter the number of battery in a edit text for example 20, after that with pressing button all 20 edit text created for enter battery voltages in every edit text. recycleveiw not usefull here

Comment: You said that before so why only repeating? And you should of course use a ListView or RecycleView.

Comment: IMO, If all `EditText`s have same size using `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` is a better solution.